# How to make Drogon Framework respect case sensitivity in MySQL table names?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using the Drogon Framework to create C++ models from my MySQL database tables. However, I'm running into an issue with the case sensitivity of the table names.

My model.json file contains the following:

```
{
"rdbms": "mysql",
"host": "[****]",
"port": [****],
"dbname": "[****]",
"schema": "public",
"user": "root",
"password": "[****]",
"tables": [
    "MyTable",
    "****",
    "****",
    "****"
],
// the rest of your config
```

}

When I run the command drogon_ctl create model models, I get the following error message:

```
Create model
mysql
Connect to server...
Source files in the models folder will be overwritten, continue(y/n)?
y
table name:mytable
Error(1146) [42S02] "Table '****.mytable' doesn't exist"
```

It's clear that Drogon is converting the table name to lower case (Alarmes to alarmes), causing the error, as MySQL is case sensitive. I tried supplying the table name as a command line argument (drogon_ctl create model models table_name=Alarmes), but the result is the same.

How can I make Drogon respect case sensitivity in MySQL table names?

Comment: I don't think you can. Look at the [source](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/blob/d00222883ff42b3253763e2895ff4874b3eccc22/drogon_ctl/create_model.cc#L446): `data["tableName"] = toLower(tableName);`. So converting to lowercase is hard-coded and there's no way to override it.

Comment: But you can try making mysql table names non-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-build drogon_ctl.exe

In drogon_ctl source code, locate the file create_model.cc.
In the line 1001.
https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/blob/e2e5d6d57f26b79bab83e87d1d3596d077925603/drogon_ctl/create_model.cc#L1001

comment the transform algorithm and recompile your drogon_ctl.exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).